# CSS Problems with jCarousel - simply cannot work it out

Tags: jquery, html, css

First of all please see the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/E9SgC/14/) I've prepared:

I understand that we shouldn't rely on externally hosted code so I will add it at the bottom of the question.

What I am trying to do is replicate the demo of the plugin [here](http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/examples/static_circular.html)

The difference is I am pulling the authors of my wordpress site and this html is outputted correctly on the page but for some reason I cannot get the avatars to sit side by side the full width of my page inside the carousel.

I have tried changing the width of `.jcarousel-skin-tango .jcarousel-container-horizontal` and `.jcarousel-skin-tango .jcarousel-clip-horizontal` and this does seem to make it wider but the distance between the avatars is increased as well so they travel in from a great distance when the buttons are pressed instead of them sitting in a horizontal line with a small gap between them.

Changing the width will mess up the next and previous buttons but that can easily be fixed to match the new carousel width.

I simply have no idea why it isn't appearing like the demo version, all I have changed is some css for the buttons.

Any help is **GREATLY** appreciated.

**CODE**

**jCarousel Initialisation**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    jQuery('#authorcarousel').jcarousel({
        scroll: 1,
        visible: 1,
        animation: 1000,
        auto: 0,
        wrap: 'circular',
        itemFallbackDimension: 75
    });
});​
```

**HTML**

```
<ul id="authorcarousel" class="jcarousel-skin-tango">
    <li>
        <img src="http://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/humano2/128x128/apps/comix.png" alt="" width="128" height="128" class="photo" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="http://cdn5.iconfinder.com/data/icons/iconshock_guys/128/andrew.png" alt="" width="128" height="128" class="photo" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="http://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/STROKE/communications/png/128/avatar.png" alt="" width="128" height="128" class="photo" /></li>
    <li>
        <img src="http://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/holloweenavatars/PNG/Frankenstein.png" alt="" width="128" height="128" class="photo" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="http://cdn5.iconfinder.com/data/icons/iconshock_guys/128/matthew.png" alt="" width="128" height="128" class="photo" />
    </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
ul#authorcarousel  {
    list-style: none;
    width: 800px;
    margin: 20px auto 50px auto;
    padding: 0;
}

#authorcarousel li {
    margin: 0 0 5px 0;
    list-style: none;
    height: 90px;
    padding: 15px 0 15px 0;
    float: left;
    width: 90px;
}

#authorcarousel img {
    width: 75px;
    height: 75px;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 10px 0 0;
    padding: 3px;
}

#authorcarousel img:hover {
    opacity: 0.7;
    cursor: pointer;
}

/* = jCarousel
----------------------------------------------- */ 
.jcarousel-skin-tango .jcarousel-container {
    background: #FFFFFF;
    border: none;
}

.jcarousel-skin-tango .jcarousel-direction-rtl {
    direction: rtl;
}

.jcarousel-skin-tango .jcarousel-container-horizontal {
    width: 100px;
    padding: 5px 20px;
} 


.jcarousel-skin-tango .jcarousel-clip {
    overflow: hidden;
}

.jcarousel-skin-tango .jcarousel-clip-horizontal {
    width:  100px;
    height: 110px;
}


.jcarousel-skin-tango .jcarousel-item {
    width: 75px;
    height: 75px;
}

.jcarousel-skin-tango .jcarousel-item-horizontal {
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

.jcarousel-skin-tango .jcarousel-direction-rtl .jcarousel-item-horizontal {
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 0;
}


.jcarousel-skin-tango .jcarousel-item-placeholder {
    background: #fff;
    color: #000;
 }

 /**
 *  Horizontal Buttons
 */
 .jcarousel-skin-tango .jcarousel-next-horizontal {
     background: #F15A23 url(http://demo.samuli.me/smartstart/img/slider-arrows-medium.png) no-repeat -5px 37px;
    filter: alpha(opacity=60);
    background: rgba(241, 90, 35, 0.6) url(http://demo.samuli.me/smartstart/img/slider-arrows-medium.png) no-repeat -5px 37px;
    color: transparent;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    font: 0/0 a;
    height: 88px;
    margin: -26.5px 0 0;
    position: absolute;
    text-shadow: none;
    top: 42%;
    left: 90%;
    width: 30px;
    z-index: 90;
    background-position: -42px 36px;    
}

.jcarousel-skin-tango .jcarousel-direction-rtl .jcarousel-next-horizontal {
    left: 5px;
    right: auto;
}

.jcarousel-skin-tango .jcarousel-next-horizontal:hover,
.jcarousel-skin-tango .jcarousel-next-horizontal:focus {
   filter: alpha(opacity=100);
   opacity: 1;
}

.jcarousel-skin-tango .jcarousel-next-horizontal:active {
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;
}

.jcarousel-skin-tango .jcarousel-next-disabled-horizontal,
.jcarousel-skin-tango .jcarousel-next-disabled-horizontal:hover,
.jcarousel-skin-tango .jcarousel-next-disabled-horizontal:focus,
.jcarousel-skin-tango .jcarousel-next-disabled-horizontal:active {
    cursor: default;
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;
}

.jcarousel-skin-tango .jcarousel-prev-horizontal {
    background: #F15A23 url(http://demo.samuli.me/smartstart/img/slider-arrows-medium.png) no-repeat -5px 37px;
    filter: alpha(opacity=60);
    background: rgba(241, 90, 35, 0.6) url(http://demo.samuli.me/smartstart/img/slider-arrows-medium.png) no-repeat -5px 37px;
    color: transparent;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    font: 0/0 a;
    height: 88px;
    margin: -26.5px 0 0;
    position: absolute;
    text-shadow: none;
    top: 42%;
    left: 17%;
    width: 30px;
    z-index: 90;
}

.jcarousel-skin-tango .jcarousel-direction-rtl .jcarousel-prev-horizontal {
    left: auto;
    right: 5px;
}

.jcarousel-skin-tango .jcarousel-prev-horizontal:hover, 
.jcarousel-skin-tango .jcarousel-prev-horizontal:focus {
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;
}

.jcarousel-skin-tango .jcarousel-prev-horizontal:active {
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;
}

.jcarousel-skin-tango .jcarousel-prev-disabled-horizontal,
.jcarousel-skin-tango .jcarousel-prev-disabled-horizontal:hover,
.jcarousel-skin-tango .jcarousel-prev-disabled-horizontal:focus,
.jcarousel-skin-tango .jcarousel-prev-disabled-horizontal:active {
    cursor: default;
    filter: alpha(opacity=60);
    opacity: 0.6;
}
```

​

​

Comment: Since this may be a CSS related problem, a link to the page would be helpful. It's a lot easier to work a solution directly on the page...

Comment: @7th I agree but it's on a dev environment so it's not publicly accessbile I'm afraid but I have made a fiddle for it that is an exact representation of the problem.

Comment: No problem... I was checking your Fiddle but I think you were still "messing around", so I couldn't see the "working carousel". Edit: You're still working on the Fiddle so I can't help much, but maybe if you add a left padding to your li's items, it may work.

Comment: hmm, should work - http://jsfiddle.net/E9SgC/14/ ?

Comment: But it's not working... I just saw it working properly once. But from what I saw, I think you should reduce the width of your li elements and add left and right padding that are equal to the width of your buttons, so the buttons will sit over the padding.

Comment: Looks like you're right, it's working in Chrome for me and I've tried shift+refreshing but it's still working, checked in Firefox and it's still sitting statically for some reason, don't know why though, everything looks fine as far as I can tell. It looks like in firefox, it can't access the actual plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Playing around a bit with the fiddle ended me with this: http://jsfiddle.net/PWdWR/

I'd say the key to resolving your issue is partially in the javascript: `visible: 6` option of jcarousel

And on the other side there's alot of the CSS that changes nothing that can be removed and the following class will adapt what you're seeing: `.jcarousel-skin-tango .jcarousel-clip-horizontal`

Comment: ah no way, can't believe it was one of the options, I should be able to take it from there and fix it up the way I want, thank you so much, this was driving me absolutely mental!

Comment: @martincarlin87 you're welcome, don't forget to mark and vote :)

Answer (score 1):

did you download the jcarousel?

they have the problem, the js is broken, check this [url](http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/lib/jquery.jcarousel.min.js)

and their [example](http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/examples/static_circular.html) does not work either:

enter [here](http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/)

and download the project, and use the local 'js'

Comment: hmm, are the two js files different?

Comment: use this: '..lib\jquery.jcarousel.min.js'

Comment: they are not different files, one is minimized, but do the same

Comment: they solved... your example is working now, but I'm still recommended to use the local file

Comment: Yip, I agree, just that for the fiddle I had to hotlink to the plugin, I am using a localfile for the actual work that I'm doing :)